# Is there a way to disable EHLO / force HELO only on an smtp server?

Tags: smtp

Is there a way with any modern (and I mean within the last 12 years) smtp server, to disable EHLO functionality and have only HELO enabled?  I'm being asked to set up some infrastructure to test something specific.  When I've searched around everything is info on what they do, not on how to stop one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on a C# library wrapped around the SMTP-protocol, it supports disabling Extended SMTP. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Is this client-side or server-side?